# Stopping an animation after scrolling to a certain point

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, scrolltop

I currently have it for images that move as you scroll down the screen (done with jQuery) but I want them to stop at a certain point.

This is the code i have at the moment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $bagSix = $("#six");
        var $bagEight = $("#eight");
        var $bagTen = $("#ten");
        var $bagTwelve = $("#twelve");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
                $bagSix
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );

        });

                $(window).scroll(function(){            
                $bagEight
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });

                $(window).scroll(function(){            
                $bagTen
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });

                $(window).scroll(function(){            
                $bagTwelve
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just stop at a specific point, you can do:

```
var new_top = Math.min($(window).scrollTop() + 30, 500);
$bagSix
.stop()
.animate({"marginTop": new_top + "px"}, "slow" );
```

This computes the new target location and makes sure it never passes 500 pixels from the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/axenoj/1/edit)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $bags = $("#six, #eight, #ten, #tweleve");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var winScrT = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(winScrT < 789 ){           // or what you prefer         
            $bags.stop().animate({marginTop: winScrT+30 }, "slow" );
        }
    });

});
```

And why not to use just a class for all your bags like :

```
var $bags = $(".bag");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, summarize the calls with the use of:

```
$("#image1, #image2, etc.")
```

Then edit your function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){            
    
$images.stop().animate({
        "marginTop": Math.min($(window).scrollTop() + 30, <stopping point>) + "px"}, "slow" );   
 });
```

Hope that helps